# JSON endpoints alongside regular actions in controllers

Tags: rest, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have a `QuizzesController` which implements all of the standard restful actions: `create`, `store`, `edit`, etc. And I also have additional `presentQuestion` and `answerQuestion`:

```php
public function presentQuestion 
{
    // . . .
    return response()->json($question);
}

public function answerQuestion($quiz_id)
{
    // . . .        
    $this->handleAnsweredQuestion($question_id);
}
```

Is it a good practice to mix the **JSON endpoints with regular php actions** in controllers, or can this design cause any unexpected problems in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem here. As long as controller has only Questions related actions everything is ok. I think it doesn't matter what you're doing - returning a view, some data, JSON or just redirecting to another page.